# 'A newer version of com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk than [5,6) is available: 4.34.0 '

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-sdk-4.x

According to the Facebook documentation, I have to add the following line in my Gradle file:

```
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
```

But I get the error:

```
A newer version of com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk than [5,6) is available: 4.34.0
```

If I set the version to 4.34.0 it seems that I don't have the latest version as I have some warnings mentioning that some methods are deprecated.

Why do I get this error message ? Should I really use [5,6) and not 4.34.0 ? By the way, what does [5,6) mean ?

Thanks !

Comment: `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:7.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:7.1.0'
```

In my Android studio it suggesting to use version `5.15.3`

[image: Use the latest version]

Comment: Thanks! I see in the change log that it is written "unreleased". What does it mean ? https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md?fbclid=IwAR2EVz24TOEI4AXYguhl6UxIMNgMr19wGLSNNBO5iu3gULftD5zvUV__uLM Thanks !